# R Shiny Application Global Variables

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Good Afternoon Everyone,

I was hoping something could help me with the following. I am creating a simple shiny application that allows user to input a date range that will then be used as an global variable to be leverage in another script when you called. The script is not able to find the StartDate1 and EndDate1 objects whenever it runs. I have tried to just write the R script within the shiny application. It appears to work when I run the application from my terminal but when I run the application from the sever I get disconnected after a few seconds. The script that is being called is using the dates selected as a parameter.

To summarize: Using shiny to allow users to select an date range that is then leverage in a R Script that is being called. The R script is not able to leverage the global variables created by the shiny.

Please see my shiny code below:

```
library(shiny)

library(shinyjs) 

PASSWORD <- "12345"
ui <- fluidPage(
useShinyjs(),
titlePanel("Daily Shiny Applications"),
br(),
br(),
br(),
passwordInput('password','Password'),
br(),

dateRangeInput(
inputId = "daterange",
label = "Select the date range",
format = "mm/dd/yyyy",  # The format of the date to display in the browser. try "mm/dd/yy"  
separator = "Between" # String to display between the start and end input boxes. try "to"
),

 fluidRow(
column(2, 
       h4("Data API:")),
column(2,
       actionButton("bttn3","Run API"), 
       p(id="bttn3_stat",))),
) 

server <- function(input, output) {

 observe({

StartDate1 <<- format(as.Date(input$daterange[1],"%B %d %Y"), "%m-%d-%Y")
EndDate1 <<-  format(as.Date(input$daterange[2],"%B %d %Y"), "%m-%d-%Y")

  })


 observeEvent(input$bttn3, {


# Change the following line for more examples
if(input$password == PASSWORD) {
  
  ########## Calling the R Scipt #######
  html("bttn1_stat3", paste0("Last Run: ", date()))
  setwd("/apps/workplace/Projects/")
  system("Rscript src/Date.R")
  
  html("bttn3_stat", "Data Download Completed!")
  
  
} else {
  html("bttn3_stat", "Incorrect Password, please try again!")
}

 })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui,
     server = server)

##The RScript####
  x <<- list(
  reportId = 250 ,
  startDate = StartDate1 ,
  endDate = EndDate1)
```

Comment: Send the dates as parameters to your script. [Here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/09/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/) you can see how it works.